# Struct Objects with ActiveRecord methods? (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory, activerecord, object

I have a limited set of objects (20 - 30) which I need to be able to combine with ActiveRecord Objects. Putting them into the DB just seems awful because I already have two other join models hooked up to the model.

So let's say i have a class

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :other_things, :class_name => 'OtherThing'
end
```

with an existing table. How would I be able to combine this with a class not inheriting from ActiveRecord (here's my best guess)

```
class OtherThing < ActiveRecord::Base
  OtherThing = Struct.new(:id, :name, :age, :monkey_fighting_ability)
  belongs_to :thing, :class_name => 'Thing'

  validate :something

  def self.search_for(something)
    MY_GLOBAL_HASH[something].map do |hash|
      instance = OtherThing.new
      hash.each_pair do |k,v|
        instance.send(:"#{k}=", v)
      end
      instance
    end
  end

  #if AR wants to call save
  def save
    return true
  end
  alias save save!

  protected
    def something
      self.errors.add(:monkey_fighting_ability, 'must be unlimited') if self.class.search_for(something).empty?
    end
end
```

Point being that I want to use ActiveRecord methods and so on without ever hitting the db. Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest reading the post on ["Make any Ruby Object Feel Like An Active Record"](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/) by Yehuda Katz. It goes over how to convert any object into a model-like class, without the database backing.

Good Luck!

Comment: I did actually. It works great for not only the case that you have, but also for validations of any object. Taking advantage of AR validations is amazing.

Comment: Sounds intriguing. Thanks again!